# Simulador de caixa eletrônico

Tags: javascript, loop

Estou começando a montar um programa que simule um caixa eletrônico com 3 opções de operações bancárias e uma opção para o usuário encerrar o processo. Só que depois da operação feita pelo usuário, eu tentei utilizar o comando de decisão múltipla `switch` `case` dentro do laço de repetição `while` para voltar ao menu inicial `do`, porém o método não deu muito certo:

```js
  var opcao, vl_saq;
  var saldo = 0;
  var min = 0;
  var max = 2000;
  do {
    opcao = parseInt(prompt("Escolha uma opção:\n1 - Saque\n2 - Depósito\n3 - Saldo\n0 - Sair")); // MENU inicial
  }
  while (opcao != 0){
    switch (opcao) {
      case 1:
        vl_saq = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor do saque:"));
        if (vl_saq > saldo) {
          if (vl_saq > 0 && vl_saq < max) {
            alert("O saque está sendo realizado...\nAperte em OK");
            saldo -= vl_saq;
            alert("Operação Realizada!");
          }
          else {
            alert("Só podem entrar no saque, valores que sejam entre R$0,00 e R$2.000,00");
          }
        }
        else{
          alert("Saldo insuficiente! Você pode sacar\nR$ "+saldo.toFixed(2));
        }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Ao executar o código, o *script* roda normalmente no navegador, mas só que ele sempre permanece no menu inicial, não executando o resto do programa.

Desta forma, qual método seria mais apropriado para resolver este caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma melhorada no código, habilitei as funções que estavam faltando, como saldo e deposito.

```
    var opcao, vl_saq;
    var saldo = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var max = 2000;
    var deposito = 0;

do {
    opcao = parseInt(prompt("Escolha uma opção:\n1 - Saque\n2 - Depósito\n3 - Saldo\n0 - Sair")); // MENU inicial
    switch (opcao) {
    case 1:
        vl_saq = parseInt(prompt("Qual o valor do saque:"));
        if (vl_saq>saldo) {
            alert("O seu saldo não é suficiente para esse saque.")
        } else {
            saldo = saldo - vl_saq;
            alert("Saque sendo Processado");
            alert("....... Retire da bandeja");
            alert("Agradecemos por utilizar os nossos serviços.");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        deposito = parseInt(prompt("Quanto você quer depositar?"))/*Opção pra saber o valor pra depositar*/
            alert("O valor de : R$ "+deposito+" foi depositado com sucesso,")
            saldo = saldo + deposito;
    case 3:

        alert("O seu saldo em conta é de : R$ "+saldo+" Deseja fazer mais alguma coisa? Espero o outro menu.")        

    }
} while (opcao != 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Existem outros problemas, mas o principal problema é o local onde está o `while`. O bloco do `do` precisa encapsular toda execução para sair apenas quando for digitado 0. Na verdade me surpreende que esta sintaxe foi aceita porque o `while` está encerrando o `do` e ao mesmo tempo iniciando outro bloco em seguida.

Um dos motivos de criar a confusão é não se preocupar com a sintaxe mais adequada. Em geral as linguagens aceitam certas formas de escrever o código e dão a impressão de ser uma coisa que na verdade não é. A sintaxe correta, e por consequência a semântica correta seria assim:

```js
var opcao, vl_saq;
var saldo = 0;
var min = 0;
var max = 2000;
do {
    opcao = parseInt(prompt("Escolha uma opção:\n1 - Saque\n2 - Depósito\n3 - Saldo\n0 - Sair")); // MENU inicial
    switch (opcao) {
    case 1:
        vl_saq = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor do saque:"));
        if (vl_saq > saldo) {
            if (vl_saq > 0 && vl_saq < max) {
                alert("O saque está sendo realizado...\nAperte em OK");
                saldo -= vl_saq;
                alert("Operação Realizada!");
            } else alert("Só podem entrar no saque, valores que sejam entre R$0,00 e R$2.000,00");
        } else alert("Saldo insuficiente! Você pode sacar\nR$ " + saldo.toFixed(2));
        break;
    }
} while (opcao != 0);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Bank.js).

Comment: Java não aceita, isso a torna uma linguagem boa? E agora Maniero? :p

Comment: Certamente melhor que JS :) Grande vantagem... :D Note que o problema é só a falta do `;` por isso o JS aceita, então não é tão surpreendente assim, a gente sabe que o JS trabalha sem o `;`.